# From a String to a Type usable as a type argument

Tags: dart, types

I'm creating a `Money` class in Dart and came up with the idea of leveraging the type system to make sure you can't subtract Swiss Francs from Dollars (as opposed to [this](https://github.com/LitGroup/money.dart/blob/master/lib/src/money.dart#L130-L135)). This works swimmingly, significantly abbreviated what I have looks as follows:

```dart
abstract class Currency {
  const Currency(this.precision, this.code);
  final int precision;
  final String code;
}

class Chf extends Currency {
  const Chf() : super(2, 'CHF');
}

class Usd extends Currency {
  const Usd() : super(2, 'USD');
}


class Money<T extends Currency> {
  Money<T> subtract(Money<T> other) { ... }
}
```

It is impossible to subtract USDs from CHFs. Great. (More complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/haarts/5d7ab193c13e6f9f4ac42589cd95f894).)
But I'm receiving JSON payloads with currency representations therein. I now need to go from a String 'CHF' to a `Money<Chf>` instance. I can't figure out how to do that.

Somewhere I need to map a (currency code) string to a `Type`.

```dart
final t = convertStringToType('CHF');
final m1 = Money<t>(100); // <- I can't do this: 't' isn't a type.'
```

The only option forward I see is having a large (colossal) switch/case statement:

```
switch(code) {
  case 'CHF':
    return Money<Chf>(100);
  ...
}
```

Clearly I don't want that. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type arguments cannot be created from scratch, they have to be actual types or other type variables. So, if you need `<Chf>` as a type argument, you need to have `<Chf>` as an actual type argument somewhere in your program. Then you can piggy-back on that.

I would do something like:

```dart
T callWithCurrency<T>(String name, T action<X extends Currency>()) {
  if (name == "CHF") return action<Chf>();
  if (name == "USD") return action<Usd>();
  ...
  throw ArgumentError.value(name, "name", "Not a recognized currency");
}
```

and then you can use it as:

```dart
final Money m1 = callWithCurrency("CHF", <X extends Currency>() => Money<X>(100));
```

Comment: What an interesting approach using the closure like that. Damn shame one can't synthesis the type argument. You don't happen to know the reason?